# 2D Isometric Cube Draw

Tags: c, opengl, drawing

I want to draw an isometric cube such as below so I can get straight edge lines for 3d graphing. The third pic is an example of what I want - straight lines on the outer cube. From experiment this doesn't work with 3D using a perspective transform.

Off the infographic I tried drawing what would be the bottom square (shear 30, rotate -30) but its still a bit off.

[image]

```
void draw_outer()
{
int ii; 
int w, h;
float equiv = 0.0f;
Matrix transform = IDENTITY_MATRIX;

w = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
h = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

equiv = h/(float)w;

//vert scale
ScaleMatrix(&projection, 1.0f, .861f, 1.0f);
//shear x adjusted for aspect ratio
ConstructShearMatrixX(&projection, .5236f * equiv);
//rotation
//fix aspect ratio
RotateAboutZ(&projection, -.5236f);
ScaleMatrix(&projection, equiv, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_ids[0], 1, GL_FALSE, model.m);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_ids[1], 1, GL_FALSE, view.m);                                     
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_ids[2], 1, GL_FALSE, projection.m);
}
```

My vertex shader is just glPosition = (Projection * View * Model * position.xyz).

[image]
[image]

Comment: From your question, it seems you're mostly having issues with building the matrix? In that case glm might be a good fit. https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html

Comment: I'd like to keep with C and using elementary transforms. I think my problem is the rotation is fixed at the bottom of the rhombus in the illustrative pic (2) rather than at its center. I'll try that tomorrow. Or if theres a way to do this differently with an orthographic projection?

*also updated the main body a bit, with a pic of current result

Comment: An isometric draw can be easily achieved by setting the camera in a corner of the "box" and looking to the opposite corner. Then use an orthografic projection.

Comment: Cool thanks this is what I wanted to know. Is there a way to make this dynamic like how would I need to rotate the camera (around which point) to change the viewing angle of the scene.